# how would i create a for loop for this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

how would I create a 'for loop' that will take the A from the strings?

because I have been struggling with it

```
name = ["Andy", "Aaron", "Ante", "Aiden", "Harvey" "Steve" ]
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read
[the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help). helpful may be
[how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Are you trying to remove the letter A from all strings?

Comment: Be clear on your expectations - what is the output? Don't ask people want to help you guessing next time.

Comment: Please make your question clear about what you want to achieve. Provide expected output.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to remove A's

```
name = ["Andy", "Aaron", "Ante", "Aiden", "Harvey" "Steve" ]
[i.replace('A','') for i in name]
```

Output:

```
['ndy', 'aron', 'nte', 'iden', 'HarveySteve']
```

if you need names with A's

```
[i for i in name if i.startswith('A')]
```

Output:

```
['Andy', 'Aaron', 'Ante', 'Aiden']
```

Comment: I am attempting to create a loop to get the four names that begin with A in the output

Comment: You can use my 2nd solution. Python strings have a method called startswith. I'll update with a link to python documentation

Answer (score 0):

You could use the split method and then just use an if statement like this:

```
for i in name:
    i.split()
    if i[0] == 'A':
        print(i)
```

You could also use regex.

If I'm understanding your question correctly, this will print out all the names that start with 'A', but you can change the print statement to something else to remove the 'A'.

Comment: Hi Rachel, that is exactly what I needed. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to remove the first 'A' from the names. Here's the code:

```
name = ["Andy", "Aaron", "Ante", "Aiden", "Harvey" "Steve" ]
for i in range(len(names)):
    if name[i][0] == 'A':
        name[i] = name[i][1:]
```

and output:

```
['ndy', 'aron', 'nte', 'iden', 'HarveySteve']
```